# Tooltip only working on certain part of href

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip, tiptip

I am trying to implement some simple tooltip (TipTip) effect, but for some weird reason i cannot get it to work:

http://basenharald.nl/3d/
Click on pssst, there you will see some social icons. I am trying to create a tooltip on the facebook icon. Wrapped a href around it (gave it a red border for testing).
Now when i hover the href the tooltip will only appear on the bottom part of the href element.

I cannot see why it does this. since the border clearly indicates that the href is fully wrapped around the icon.

Some help would be appreciated.
So far i tried to set: height, z-index, display:block (makes the layout fall apart), float. Nothing seems to work.

Furthermore. I want the tooltip to apear on the bottom. This works fine as long as i do not scroll to the right. When scrolled to the right it apears on the left and the layout breaks.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a div with class="tab" that overlays (z-index: 999) your panel.

Comment: How stupid is that! i did not see that. Thanks for the advice. What about the other part of the problem? The "after scrolling it loads on the left" part? If you know how to fix that, i can mark this as the right answer

Comment: I can´t seem to recreate the problem. The layout doesn´t break in neither IE 7 och latest FF.

Comment: Do you not see when you scroll a little to the right (or for example click muziek) when you hover the icons it appears on the left? It is not that the layout of the page breaks, the layout of the tooltip does. For me it happens in IE, FF and Chrome

Comment: This should do it; `#tiptip_holder { white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: Thank you so much! It does not work fully, but now i know how to make a workaround for it so I will mark this as the answer